# Collapsing chart inside Scroll View

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

im new Andriod Dev, im trying to use scroll view with a linear layout inside. the linear layout gets filled with View at runtime. The view is used to create a chart. The problem is the chart i draw is getting collapsed on page open here is the chart xml i got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="750px"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_ParentScroll">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100px"
            android:minHeight="100px"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_ScrollChart" />            
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is my activity onCreate method

```
 SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ScrollableChart);

            LinearLayout laout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout_ScrollChart);
            int[] values = { 700, 400, 100, 500, 600 };
            Color[] color_values = { Color.Magenta, Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Yellow, Color.Cyan };
            String[] itemnames = { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", "item 6" };
            ExtendedPieChart chart = new ExtendedPieChart(this, itemnames, values, color_values);
            laout.AddView(chart);
            laout.SetBackgroundColor(Color.WhiteSmoke);
```

Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Note: i dont have enough reputation to post pictures to better explain the issue.

Comment: try setting android:layout_height to MATCH_PARENT in both scrollview and linear layouts

Comment: didnt work, im not able to see the graph if i set android:layout_height to MATCH_PARENT.

Comment: Can you also post your expendedpiechart class? There is no problem with the xml. It should wrap it's content properly. You may try laout.Invalidate() after you add the view